# How do you apply a gloss and spec map on one cycles material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have never seen anyone apply a gloss and a spec. map in cycles and I would be very interested to see how this is done so I can start using the gloss textures I have from gametextures.com. Some also have a height map which I assume I am supposed to just use on a displacement modifier.

Comment: You can use the gloss or spec map as factor when mixing between diffuse and glossy shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples to illustrate some of the possibilities of nodes using a single texture like this:[image]

Using the texture as color on a glossy shader.

[image]

Using the texture as roughness on the glossy shader, the roughness value is determined by the brightness of the image, dark areas are more reflective.

[image]

Using the image as Roughness on the glossy shader and as Displacement (bump map) on the material output:

[image]

Using the image as a mix factor for two different shaders:

[image]

Using an RGB Curves node to alter the contrast of the image used as factor.

[image]

Using RGB curves to control the displacement

[image]

As you can see, there are quite a number possibilities for endless fun.

Answer (score 8):

I used the 4 images on their [pricing page](http://gametextures.com/blog/pricing/#x-content-band-7) in my demo.

<sub>Click for full size</sub>
[image: cycles nodes]

The *Albedo Map* goes in to the *Diffuse* node as the base color.
The *Specular Map* goes in to the *Glossy* node as the specular color. (metals are one of the few materials that have a colored specular highlight.)
The *Gloss Map* is used as the mix factor in the *Mix Shader* node between the diffuse and the glossy.
The *Normal Map* get plugged in to a *Normal Map* node then connected to both the diffuse and the glossy nodes.

Comment: gloss maps should be inverted and plugged into the roughness input

Comment: @SebastiánMestre not necessarily. Granted changing the roughness is a way to make a material less glossy in parts, it is not the only way, nor even the "correct" way. I would suggest you try to make a glossy material, with parts of it not glossy and having a color by just changing the roughness. You will see that you need to "mix" the glossy on top of the diffuse base color.

Answer (score 1):

Gloss maps should be inverted and plugged into the roughness input of glossy shaders.

Specular maps should be plugged into either a mix node factor input or into a glossy shader's color input (if the material is a metal do the later and do the former if it isn't).

Height maps can be plugged into the displacement input of your material output, fed through a bump node or used in a displacement modifier.