# AO, Bump, Normal, Albedo, Depth, Gloss, hi-gloss and roughness

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I get a nice texture with AO, Bump, Normal, Albedo, Depth, Gloss, hi-gloss and roughness images texture. How i can put all images in cycles nodes for a realistic textures, i know the composition of nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do you apply a gloss and spec map on one cycles material?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27475/2217) and [How are texture maps imported into Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217)