# All in one node setup for most texture map types?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

Is there a node setup that anybody may show that will allow you to easily put in most texture maps in one simple set up. For example something like Andrew Prices PBR material nodes. But instead have options that will say the texture maps of color, gloss, AO, spec, depth, bump, normal etc. and then by puting only the texture maps you put in (through image texture node) and will produce your output with what you have put and the empty sockets will be ignored and the sockets you have used have a slider.

If nothing like that exists or it will be very dificult to build, what is the general node stup so that if I have all of these maps (or most of them if not all).

I believe that this question only shows only a few of the maps:

[How do you apply a gloss and spec map on one cycles material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/how-do-you-apply-a-gloss-and-spec-map-on-one-cycles-material)

Comment: Three Nodes for the Blender-kings under the sky,
Seven for the Dwarf-textures in their halls of stone,
Nine for Noobs doomed to die,
One for the Dark Render on his 3D-Printed throne
In the Land of Stackechange where the Shadows lie.
One Node to rule them all, One Node to find them,
One Node to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

Comment: Have you looked into the [Principled Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html) available in v 2.79?

Comment: Well I wanted to see something specificly for them. I love the Lord of the Rings speech!

Comment: The Lord of the Nodes...

Comment: Well if I was to use the pricipled shader, where would each map go?

Comment: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2017/6/21/how-to-use-blenders-new-ultimate-shader-principled-bsdf

Comment: How do you add a depth map?