# I need a certain pattern on a particular texture to be glossy

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I need certain patterns on a particular texture to be glossy while everything else remains rough. Any ideas?
It more like a golden yarn embroidered on a black linen.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/how-do-you-apply-a-gloss-and-spec-map-on-one-cycles-material